# Prevent windows applications from accessing data in my profile.

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions

When a program tries to modify something inside **Program Files** folder, Windows 7 gives a security warning and asks whether I allow it or not.

I want to set a similar warning, so that programs trying to access **MyStuff** folder should ask for permission. I even want a warning when they try to read files within this folder.

I don't want to install 3rd party software for it if possible.

**Edit:**

basically I want to make sure my personal folder (emails, documents, contracts, IP) is not being exposed by random software I download.

Answer (score 1):

> basically I want to make sure my personal folder (emails, documents, contracts, IP) is not being exposed by random software I download.

If we're talking "random software", then [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) might be your thing.

> Sandboxie runs your programs in an isolated space which prevents them from making permanent changes to other programs and data in your computer.
>
> [image: Animation]
>
> [image: Legend]

It doesn't do exactly what you want right away, though. From the FAQ:

> It should be noted, however, that Sandboxie does not typically stop sandboxed programs from reading your sensitive data. **However, by careful configuration of the ClosedFilePath and ClosedKeyPath settings, you can achieve this goal as well.**

Comment: thank you, i will go with this for now, but it will require me to heavily transform my work habits. i downloaded it and i am already experimenting with it